# App-specific files on Android are deleted at startup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-file

I create a file at the onCreate callback following the [Android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific?hl=en)

```
File folderSamples = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    File test = new File(folderSamples, "text.txt");

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(test);
        fw.write("hello there");
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

The file is created correctly and I can open it on the device manager.
My problem is that when I reboot the application on Android Studio the file is deleted, I don't see it on the device manager and the application can't find it...what do I do wrong? Are those file meant to be deleted everytime the application is started?
Thank you for your replies.

Comment: `My problem is that when I reboot the application on Android Studio` You mean: My problem is that when I reboot the application on my Android device. ? Or what are you doing?

Comment: Files in getFilesDir() will only be deleted by Android at deinstall of app.

Comment: I stop it on Android studio (red square) and restart it later

Comment: I dont know what you do. I dont remember such square. But just take your Android device and start and stop your app there.

Comment: The red square in AS is not stopping an app but killing it. But that should not have an effect on the created files. But AS also has the ability to clear app data (which implicitly kills the app) so may be you have reconfigured the stop button to clear app data instead?